# Work on a page-by-page environment

Tags: pdftex, page

I was wondering if there was any way for me to simply work rather than by sections (if that makes any sense) but by pages. Desired effect would be this:

```
\begin{page}{Introduction}{Introduction Subheading}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{page}
\begin{page}{Chapter 1}{Chapter 1 Subheading}
    \lipsum[3-6]
\end{}
```

and it owuld output two pages.

There are a few options for content that spans multiple pages. it could.

1. Overflow content onto the next page (same as outside of environment)
2. Overflow content into the void between pages.
3. Change text spacing
4. Depend on parameters to decide one of the above

Personally, I would use either 3 or 4.

Comment: See the beamer document class (substitute `frame` for `page`)

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's super smart! I'll submit an answer once I get a working environment.